# How to open broswer in my app?

Tags: java, android

i'm just getting started with Android Studio. I want to know how can i access the broswer, giving it a certain URL (that in the future will be the IP address of an IP camera).

Comment: Use webview for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

That works fine for me.

As for the missing "http://" I'd just do something like this:

```
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
   url = "http://" + url;
```

Comment: Can we maybe *not* copy answers wholesale from duplicate questions? Or at least reference the person who initially has given the answer?